# IIS output caching setting using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, iis, automation

I have been trying to find a way to configure the IIS 'outputcaching' setting.  I have been looking around and having really had anything that works.  I am basically trying to set output caching for an extension .pdf and the setting "until changed".  
I've tried this code:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web 
Site' -Filter "system.webServer/caching/profiles/add[@extension='.pdf']" -
Name "kernelCachePolicy" -Value "CacheUntilChange"
```

but that gave me the following error:

> WARNING: Target configuration object 'system.webServer/caching/profiles/add[@extension='.pdf'] is not found at path 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'.

Comment: Try using Add-WebConfigurationProperty

Comment: Thank you ArcSet that I didn't get the error message but it did not add the rule for ouput caching.

Comment: Press the up mark on my comment please

Comment: I tried logging in and out but I am unable to see the up arrow on your comments.

Comment: Thank you Ill just Put a replay and you can mark accepted

Comment: Just and update I also tried making a new website to test and also tried this on a Server 2012 machine with IIS 8 still have the same results that I am unable to add a webconfigurationproperty.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Add-WebConfigurationProperty

Add-WebConfigurationProperty Will add a property that isn't there.

Set-WebConfigurationProperty Changes the value of a property that already exists

Comment: Thanks ArcSet but the system will not yet allow me to upvote for being a new member.  I tried using the Add-WebConfigurationProperty but this does not seem to do anything.  

I used the same code as I had above just changed set to add.

Comment: Just an update,  I created a value using the IIS GUI and then tried changing with Set-WebConfigurationProperty and it did work so I'm not sure what is not letting me add a property.

Comment: Has anyone else had any problems trying to use Add-WebconfigurationProperty?

Comment: No error but when I check the output caching in IIS there is nothing added there.

Comment: Really stuck on this one I can fully change the value using Set-weconfigurationProperty, but when you add-configurationproperty the command goes through and nothing is added.  Has anyone else had a issue like this?